# How to get excerpt in Draft JS?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I want to show only the first N characters of content within draft js. However, it can't be just simply sliced because, there is a possibility of creating invalid DOM (example: opening of p tag but no closing p tag).

At the moment, I am just displaying all the content using "draft-js-export-html" and "dompurify" packages. Kindly let know of a way to create an except.

Answer (score 0):

Found a package, that seems to working. It creates excerpts in Javascript from HTML content.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/excerpt-html